# sleep() function not working as expected

Tags: c, plot, sleep

I had a similar problem earlier but what's happening now is that I'm trying to use GNU libplot to draw five circles, wait a few seconds, then have the window go black. What's happening is the screen starts black, waits the specified amount of time, then draws. How do I use sleep to get my desired output? I'm going to leave out the code where I assign values to my structs for time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <plot.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct body {
char color[10];
char size[4];
char mass[10];
char xpos[10];
char ypos[10];
};

int main() {

    struct body sun;
    struct body mercury;
    struct body venus;
    struct body earth;
    struct body mars;

    plPlotter *plotter;
    plPlotterParams *plotterParams;

    plotterParams = pl_newplparams();
    pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "BITMAPSIZE", "750x750");
    pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "USE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING", "no");
    pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "BG_COLOR", "black");

    if ((plotter = pl_newpl_r("X", stdin, stdout, stderr, plotterParams)) == NULL) {
        fprint(stderr, "Couldn't create Plotter\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if(pl_openpl_r(plotter) < 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open Xwindows Plotter\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    pl_fspace_r(plotter, -2500, -2500, 2500, 2500);

    pl_pentype_r(plotter, 1);
    pl_filltype_r(plotter, 1);

    pl_pencolorname_r(plotter, "black");

    /* draw the sun */
    pl_fillcolorname_r(plotter, sun.color);
    pl_fcircle_r(plotter, atof(sun.size), atof(sun.ypos), atof(sun.size));

    /* I do this same thing 4 more times but with 
     * mercury, venus, earth, and mars
    */

    sleep(5); /* try to wait 5 seconds then sleep */

    /* close and cleanup */
    if (pl_close_pl_r(plotter) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldnt delete plotter\n");
    }
    else if (pl_deletepl_r(plotter) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldnt delete plotter\n");
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but have you tried setting `"USE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING"` to `"yes"`?

Comment: Just tried and it does the same thing. Shows black screen for a moment then draws my circles

Answer (score 0):

Where you are:

```
plotterParams = pl_newplparams();
pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "BITMAPSIZE", "750x750");
pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "USE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING", "no");
pl_setplparam(plotterParams, "BG_COLOR", "black");
```

you have the "BG_COLOR" set to black.

I don't know a whole lot about this particular set of tools, but it looks like you are setting the background to black from the start.

What you want to do in your case is to set it initially to white (or whatever) then change it to black after you are done. Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: `C` doesn't have a `try..catch` construct.

Comment: @SnappawapaI want the background color to be black the whole time. I have 5 circles that I want to be drawn onto the black background. After 5 seconds I want the circles to disappear and just leave the background showing.

Comment: right, that's not what you originally said. In that case, you will want to re- draw over your circles in black, to match the background

Comment: @Snappawapa, you mean wait the 5 seconds then just draw black circles at the same locations? Or do you know how to change the foreground color by any chance?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just change the color of the drawers to black and redraw the circles at the same locations.

and I do not know if changing the foreground is an option, not too familiar with the tools you are using. There could also be a method to clear whats was drawn but you would have to research it. I personally would just draw back over them though